# What is a good way to handle database objects in python classes?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pylons

Should I access global db object directly from within the methods of each class?  Or from each method, should I instantiate an instance of the db object?

One of my database objects changes depending on the id of the info being accessed so it is created through a function connectToDatabase(id).  Should I make this a global function, have it return a database object and instantiate it from each method, or something else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLAlchemy suggests that a function which creates the session be global.

http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/reference/orm/sessions.html#sqlalchemy.orm.sessionmaker

> It is intended that the sessionmaker()
>   function be called within the global
>   scope of an application, and the
>   returned class be made available to
>   the rest of the application as the
>   single class used to instantiate
>   sessions.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, like in many others, I prefer [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection): have your class (e.g in its `__init__`) accept the DB connection as an argument.

This makes it easier and cleaner to test, lets you switch strategies as needed (e.g. to move to a "pool of DB connections" strategy if you find otherwise you're making too many DB connections at once), and distributes responsibilities more accurately and flexibly.

In general, I think of Dependency Injection as probably the most important Design Pattern that was not listed in the great "Gang of 4" book!-)